# Wanna prevent MongoDB or JavaScript scripting execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, security, scripting

I´m building up a proyect with NodeJS, JavaScript and MongoDB and wanna prevent scripting execution. I´ve searched for a long time and I found the node module ("sanitize") but is all time working wrong with errors like "Error Invalid type" (when I use STRING for sanitize).

Also don´t know how prevent MongoDB scripting and is a thing that is worrying me a lot.

I keep reading Mongo, Node and JavaScript forums and post here on StackOverflow about this, but I think this post can be interesting for future developers that like me, are starting on security stuff of programing.

Any help would be well recived! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you should try this:

`const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');`

// Data sanitization against NoSQL query injection
`app.use(mongoSanitize());`